# Reusing UIWebView is causing crashes

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I've read that reusing UIWebViews is kind of a bad practice. Some code I inherited at work is pushing a variety of content to a UIWebView. Powerpoints, Word documents, and video. This all works just fine under normal circumstances. When we get to switching out the content in the UIWebView too fast, it dumps.

My webView is set as a property. It is hooked up in IB just fine. Normal selection from our tableView loads local content just fine. It takes rapid fire selection of either the same cell or combinations of multiple to get it to crash.

I can capture some error messages for it for the webViewDidFailWithError. But those will trigger even without a crash. 
Here is the error localized string.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

When the app does finally crash, it blows up on this goofy WebCore error.

[image: Application Crash image]

If anyone has any links or some code examples how to handle this I would appreciate it. Maybe an example how to best reuse my webView property without blowing things up.

I would load some of my code, but there is a lot going on not related to the webView itself. All content being pushed to the webView is done via `[self.webView loadRequest:request];` with the request being an NSURLRequest filled with the path to the local content.

I will be very appreciative if anyone can help me out on this one. Fingers crossed for something simple.

Comment: Maybe you should block user interaction while your webView loads request.

Comment: That might be possible, but not sure our client will go for it. I'll take that under consideration. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it with `@try {} @catch {}`?

Comment: Is the UIWebView only handled on the main thread, as it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain this way is the "best" way to solve the issue, but it does seem to be working quite well. Short, sweet, and it works.

I disabled userInteraction with the tableView that updates the content in the webView. Since you have to mash on it so much, missing a tap here or there probably won't be missed. So for now, this is the fix.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate methods

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

// I re-enable on load failures as they can block you out entirely on fail
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it’s crashing only when you tap quickly, could you put a gesture recognizer over it to act as a poor man's rate limiter?

Comment: Gesture recognizer over the tableView -didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Over whichever view is triggering the requests, so that you don't send them too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `[webview stopLoading];` before loading another request? What you might need to do is cancel or stop the current loading before trying to load a different one. The other option being restrict the user input.

Comment: I have tried putting [self.webView stopLoading]; before I call the new loadRequest, but it doesn't make any difference, still crashes.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is within that area. If it only crashes when you quickly tap then the problem has to be with the multiple requests. As for restricting user input it doesn't have to be until it finishes loading. You could try ignoring the touches for a half or full second to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it would fix it. But doesn't really solve the problem. I can hammer on it pretty quick and it holds up. Really only crashes with unrealistic tapping. Work would like me to figure out how to prevent crashes, if it is even possible. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Here is a little more info for you. I created a project with a webView and created 2 buttons that switched between two different requests. I tapped them both as fast as I could and tapped them together but it never crashed. Did this both on the simulator and on the device.

Comment: We are loading up saved content on the device. Word documents, PDF's, Powerpoints. I'm flipping back and forth between 2 .pptx files. Thanks for the effort. I can click the same button reloading the same file over and over pretty good. But if I go fast enough, it will eventually crash.

Comment: I tried the same thing in a new project, I was able to get it to crash. Here is my line to load the webview. [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"ppt"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Answer (score 0):

In your UIWebViewDelegate, you could implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to return `NO` if there is already a request loading.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think you'd be better off not re-using the UIWebView. Ditch the nib, create it programmatically and set it to nil and re-create/re-assign/re-alloc it when the data source changes.

On a different note I would make sure to use NSOperationQueue for the data loading.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately my hands are tied in the matter. We did figure out how to get around it. We are creating a UIView with a progress indicator showing it is still loading and keeping the user from overloading the webview. It works, customer happy, all I can hope for. Thanks for the advice.