# Connection Error Occurs When Browsing Too Fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In the app that I'm writing, I check to see if the device has an internet connection. I put a connection error image over the screen, and hide it unless the device is not connected. There is an odd issue though. I implemented a simple back button for the `UIWebView`, but when I press it too fast, the connection error occurs. Here is the code I use to check for connection, and decide whether to display the error:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    _connectionError.hidden = NO;
}
```

So, I think the only way to solve this issue would be to have it check if there is a connection one time, only when the app first launches, and never run again for the remainder of the time. I'm extremely new to Objective-C, and have no idea how to do this. I'm thinking that I should put something in `viewDidLoad`, or implement some way to have the method run only once, but I have no idea how to do that.

Here's the code for the back button:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [_viewWeb goBack];
}
```

Comment: How do you implement the back button? Can you post your code?

Comment: @verbumdei Yes sir, I just posted it.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235485/reusing-uiwebview-is-causing-crashes and try to set [_viewWeb stopLoading]; before calling the goBack method.

Comment: @verbumdei Setting `[_viewWeb stopLoading];` before calling the goBack method did it buddy, thanks a lot! Could you post that as an answer so that I can throw you some points?

Comment: Sure, just posted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method stopLoading on the webView before the goBack method to make sure there is no multiple request going which can cause the connection error:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [_viewWeb stopLoading];
    [_viewWeb goBack];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for a connection you can use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) in your project. You can then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195012/how-to-use-reachability-class-to-detect-valid-internet-connection) answer to see how to use it. This would be more efficient and cleaner than using a UIWebview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that Reachability uses push notifications though to display the message, is this correct?

Comment: It doesn't have to. You can check `if(([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable))` for example, to check if there is an internet connection available. This can be checked from anywhere after importing `Reachability.h`.

Comment: @Oral B I should add that you can try using this method before trying to actually load a web page; doing so could save you some hassle